# Select individual lines from feature class, convert to unique rasters: "raise e" error?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, raster-conversion

I have a feature class with 5 lines in it, and need select each one and turn them into its own raster -- for example, line 1 is raster 1, line 2 is raster 2, etc. This is the python script:

```
import arcpy

SightLines = "C:\\temp\\SightLines.shp"

index = 0
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(SightLines)
for row in rows:
    RasterFileName = "C:\\temp\\fakeData.gdb\\Raster" + str(index)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Raster File " + RasterFileName)
    arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion(row, "FID", RasterFileName, "1")
    arcpy.AddMessage(" >> MADE SUCCESSFULLY")
    index = index + 1
```

Unfortunately, this is throwing the following error at the FeatureToRaster_conversion step:

```
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

I can't figure out what *raise e* is trying to tell me. What exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "FeatureToRaster" conversion tool works on a feature class as a whole.  You are passing it a row object, and this does not work.  You would first need to extract each line as its own feature class, then convert that to a raster, then you can delete the temporary feature class.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of exporting a separate feature class per line, create a feature layer instead- This will speed things up since no new features need to be written to disk (feature layers are in memory).